# CursorLoader do not refresh view -- android

Tags: android, listview, android-cursorloader

I have done a searchview in action bar.

But when I type the search, in theory the listview, has to refresh, but it doesn't. I know that it does ok, because i "Print" the content of the cursor.

Probably I'm missing something, but I'm not finding it.

**Code:**

*method "doFilter()":*

```
public synchronized void doFilter(String filterString) {

        mSearchString = filterString;

        if (nSearchChatViewPagerAdapter == null) {

            nSearchChatViewPagerAdapter = new ChatViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            mChatPager.setAdapter(nSearchChatViewPagerAdapter);

            mLoaderCallbacks = new MyLoaderCallbacks();
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(CHAT_PAGE_LOADER_ID , null, mLoaderCallbacks);
        } else {

            if (!mAwaitingUpdate)
            {
                mAwaitingUpdate = true;
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable ()
                {

                    public void run ()
                    {

                        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(CHAT_PAGE_LOADER_ID , null, mLoaderCallbacks);
                        mAwaitingUpdate = false;
                    }
                },1000);
            }

        }
    }
```

*LoaderCallback:*

```
class MyLoaderCallbacks implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

            if (mSearchString != null) {

                buf.append('(');
                buf.append("contacts.username");
                buf.append(" LIKE ");
                android.database.DatabaseUtils.appendValueToSql(buf, "%" + mSearchString + "%");
                buf.append(" OR ");
                buf.append("contacts.nickname");
                buf.append(" LIKE ");
                android.database.DatabaseUtils.appendValueToSql(buf, "%" + mSearchString + "%");
                buf.append(')');
            }           

            CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(NewChatActivity.this, Imps.Contacts.CONTENT_URI_CHAT_CONTACTS, ChatView.CHAT_PROJECTION,
                    buf == null ? null : buf.toString(), null, Imps.Contacts.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

            loader.setUpdateThrottle(50L);

            return loader;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor newCursor) {
            nSearchChatViewPagerAdapter.swapCursor(newCursor);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
            nSearchChatViewPagerAdapter.swapCursor(null);

        }

    }
```

*Adapter:*

```
public class ChatViewPagerAdapter extends DynamicPagerAdapter {
        Cursor mCursor;
        boolean mDataValid;

        public ChatViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public Cursor getCursor() {
            return mCursor;
        }

        public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
            if (newCursor == mCursor) {
                return null;
            }
            Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
            mCursor = newCursor;
            Log.v("MIAAAAAAAAAAAU", android.database.DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(mCursor));
            if (newCursor != null) {
                mDataValid = true;
                // notify the observers about the new cursor
                refreshChatViews();

            } else {
                mDataValid = false;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return oldCursor;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if (mCursor != null)
                return mCursor.getCount() + 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0)
            {
                if (mContactList == null)
                    mContactList = new ContactListFragment();


                return mContactList;
            }
            else
            {
                int positionMod = position - 1;

                mCursor.moveToPosition(positionMod);
                long contactChatId = mCursor.getLong(ChatView.CONTACT_ID_COLUMN);
                String contactName = mCursor.getString(ChatView.USERNAME_COLUMN);
                long providerId = mCursor.getLong(ChatView.PROVIDER_COLUMN);

                return ChatViewFragment.newInstance(contactChatId, contactName, providerId);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

            if (object instanceof ChatViewFragment)
            {
                ChatViewFragment cvFrag = (ChatViewFragment)object;
                ChatView view = cvFrag.getChatView();
                long viewChatId = view.mLastChatId;
                int position = PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;

                // TODO: cache positions so we don't scan the cursor every time
                if (mCursor != null && mCursor.getCount() > 0)
                {
                    mCursor.moveToFirst();

                    int posIdx = 1;

                    do {
                        long chatId = mCursor.getLong(ChatView.CHAT_ID_COLUMN);

                        if (chatId == viewChatId)
                        {
                            position = posIdx;
                            break;
                        }

                        posIdx++;
                    }
                    while (mCursor.moveToNext());

                }

               //` Log.d(TAG, "position of " + cvFrag.getArguments().getString("contactName") + " = " + position);
                return position;

            }
            else if (object instanceof ContactListFragment)
            {
                return 0;

            }
            else {
                throw new RuntimeException("got asked about an unknown fragment");
            }
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            if (position == 0 || mCursor == null)
            {
                if (mShowChatsOnly)
                    return getString(R.string.title_chats);
                else
                    return getString(R.string.contacts);
            }
            else
            {
                int positionMod = position - 1;

                mCursor.moveToPosition(positionMod);
                if (!mCursor.isAfterLast())
                {


                    String nickname = mCursor.getString(ChatView.NICKNAME_COLUMN);
                    int presence = mCursor.getInt(ChatView.PRESENCE_STATUS_COLUMN);
                    int type = mCursor.getInt(ChatView.TYPE_COLUMN);

                    BrandingResources brandingRes = mApp.getBrandingResource(mCursor.getInt(ChatView.PROVIDER_COLUMN));


                    SpannableString s = null;

                    Drawable statusIcon = null;

                    if (Imps.Contacts.TYPE_GROUP == type)
                    {
                        s = new SpannableString(nickname);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s = new SpannableString("+ " + nickname);
                        statusIcon = brandingRes.getDrawable(PresenceUtils.getStatusIconId(presence));
                        statusIcon.setBounds(0, 0, statusIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                                statusIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());
                        s.setSpan(new ImageSpan(statusIcon), 0, 1, SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                    }


                    return s;

                }
                else
                    return "";//unknown title
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int pos) {
            Object item = super.instantiateItem(container, pos);
            if (pos > 0) {
                ChatViewFragment frag = (ChatViewFragment)item;
            }
            return item;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int pos, Object object) {

            super.destroyItem(container, pos, object);
        }

        public ChatView getChatViewAt(int pos) {
            if (pos > 0)
            {
                ChatViewFragment frag = ((ChatViewFragment)getItemAt(pos));

                if (frag != null)
                    return frag.getChatView();
            }

            return null; //this can happen if the user is quickly closing chats; just return null and swallow the event
            //throw new RuntimeException("could not get chat view at " + pos);
        }
    }
```

*LogCat:*

```
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285): >>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@307d2543
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285): 0 {
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285):    _id=5
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285):    account=1
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285):    provider=1
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285):    username=prova@mail.es
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285):    nickname=Prova Prova
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285):    type=0
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285):    mode=0
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285):    last_unread_message=null
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285):    _id=5
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285):    subscriptionType=null
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285):    subscriptionStatus=null
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285):    avatars_data=NULL
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285): }
01-14 12:52:09.025: V/MIAAAAAAAAAAAU(21285): <<<<<
```

*Image of the 2 items* I have in the list. I supposed that when i Press, "P" or more, the item "melissak" has to dessapear.

[image]

Comment: It ate my head for quite a while - While this might not be an exact answer to your question - I ended up using a filterQueryProvider. Let me know if you want an example.

Comment: Yes FilterQueryProvider is a path you should follow

Comment: @Skynet if you can paste me an example.. please ^^ (never used filterQueryProvider). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

I must also tell you that this way is not too efficient but currently its th eonly way which is working for me:

in your onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu); 
        searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
```

At Class level:

```
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText){

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
                searchView.clearFocus();
                CursorAdapter filterAdapter = (CursorAdapter) Cur;
                filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
            }
            else {
                CursorAdapter filterAdapter = (CursorAdapter) Cur;
                filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Anywhere in your OnCreate:

```
Cur.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return dbHelper.getDirectoryList(constraint);
            }
        });
```

This goes into your DBAdapter:

```
public Cursor getDirectoryList(CharSequence constraint) {
        open(); 
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.setTables(DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1);

        String asColumnsToReturn[] = { DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.id + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.notificationfor + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.datetonotify + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.isextraordinary + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.notificationdata + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.primaryid + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.type_notifications + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.radio_type_notfi + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.friend_name_not + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.notif_image_Uri + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.notifDob + "," + DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE1 + "."
                + DBAdapter.notificationdatefor };

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Notifications ORDER BY SUBSTR(DATE('NOW'), 0)>SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0), SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0)";
            return mDb.rawQuery(query, null);


        } else {
            String value = "%" + constraint.toString() + "%";
            return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE1,asColumnsToReturn,"NotificationDateFor like ? OR NotificationDateFor like ? ORDER BY DateToNotify ASC ",new String[] { value, value }, null,null, null);

        }
    }
```

Note: return mDb.query is very important here. So modify your query accordingly. Cur is your main cursor with which you load into the ListView.

Comment: Let me know if this helps and you make it more elegant - I would be pleased to implement more in the above for my own purpose too!!

Comment: Ok, I'll try in these days. ;) Thanks!

Comment: I've been looking for your code and how to implement in mine... and just say that will be very very hard. Because i'm using  CursorLoader with, content providers...etc etc... :(

Comment: Oh mate! Thats sad, I will keep posting if I find anything relevant!